# Unresolved external typedef while compiling with X11

Tags: c, macos, opengl, glut

I'm compiling an app using quake qgl api on X11/FreeGLUT (OSX 10.12) 
Compilation fails with errors like this:

```
/ref_gl/qgl.h:579:8: error: unknown type name     'PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DEXTPROC'; 
did you mean 'PFNGLXBINDTEXIMAGEEXTPROC'?
extern PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DEXTPROC             glTexImage3DEXT;
```

Seems that external typedefs ( PFNGLPNTRIANGLESIATIPROC, PFNGLPNTRIANGLESFATIPROC, PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DEXTPROC ...) couldn't be found by the compiler.

UPD: Instructions I'm following: sourceforge. net/projects/quake2xp/files/linux%20release/

Please, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: use only X11 GL library for this project.
The error was caused because of mixing OpenGL prefixes in the #import directives:

```
#include <OpenGL/... > (Native MacOS)  and  #include <GL/...> (X11)
```

Only

```
#include <GL/...>
```

prefix should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use X11 on MacOS. X11 is not the native graphics system of MacOS and the X11 server that comes with MacOS does not have advanced OpenGL support.

Use the native MacOS OpenGL framework.

Comment: In my case i need X11, because the app requires X11 extensions (according to the  tutorial i'm following). After having removed X11 flag from my script (so Xcode's OpenGL is used only), the error is `./client/../ref_gl/qgl.h:30:12: fatal error: 'GL/glx.h' file not found`

Comment: What specific X11 extensions does that app require? Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: App project written for linux/X11.  (I'm trying it, cause version for Mac OS does't exist :(  ) Tutorial :  `sourceforge. net/projects/quake2xp/files/linux%20release/`